# WSO2 API Manager Data Analytics Server Version Compatibility

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

Is Latest Version of WSO2 API Manager(2.0.0) compatible with latest version of WSO DAS(3.1.0)?

In the download page of WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0, only WSO DAS 2.0.0 download is mentioned for Analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are compatible.

2nd question is not much clear. Could you please tell where it says about `DAS 2.0.0`? Actually, there is no version 2.0.0 in DAS. It was called BAM before.

If you're talking about `wso2am-analytics-2.0.0.zip` pack, it's a customized version of `DAS 3.0.x`. It has required CAR files installed and is configured to work with APIM, with less manual configurations.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. 
wso2am-analytics-2.0.0.zip - I took it as version 2.0.0. Thanks for pointing out the error.
Does WSO2 DAS have any reporting feature? Any idea how to generate API usage reports?
TIA, 
Jai

Comment: DAS can't generate reports yet.

Comment: @jai, if you want to generate report you can setup with a billing engine. you can refer following article to generate report using a sample billing engine.